# Simple implementation of operators between different c++ classes

Tags: c++, operators

Is there a simple/smart way to implement the missing operator: `‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘myclassRef<int>’ and ‘myclass<int>’)` with these two classes?
I know that I could just define a function that takes these two types as parameters.
But since I am implementing several function that should take both `myclass` and `myclassRef` types as parameters I would like to do it in a simple manner.

I have been looking into having `myclassRef` as a inner class of `myclass` and using implicit conversion, however this method (to the best of my knowledge) required all function using both types as parameters to be member functions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct myclass;

template <class T>
struct myclassRef
{
    T* i;

    myclassRef(myclass<T>* A)
    {
        i = &A->i;
    }

    operator myclass<T>()
    {
        return myclass<T>(*i);
    }

    T& get()
    {
        return *i;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct myclass
{
    T i;

    myclass() = default;
    myclass(const myclass&) = default;
    myclass(T _i) : i(_i) {}

    myclassRef<T> ref()
    {
        return myclassRef<T>(this);
    }

    T& get()
    {
        return i;
    }

    T get() const
    {
        return i;
    }
};

template <class T>
myclass<T>& operator+=(myclass<T>& lhs, const myclass<T>& rhs)
{
    lhs.get() += rhs.get();
    return lhs;
}

template <class T>
myclass<T> operator+(const myclass<T>& lhs, const myclass<T>& rhs)
{
    myclass<T> res(lhs);
    res += rhs;
    return res;
}

int main() {
    myclass<int> A(5);
    myclass<int> B(2);

    auto C = A + B;

    std::cout << C.i << std::endl;

    auto D = C.ref();

    A = D + B;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution for my problem using `template template` parameters. This approach allows me the the two classes interchangeably. However, it required a few changes to the two classes. For `myclassRef` I had to add a `const` version of `get()` and set `myclass` as a `friend class`. For `myclass` I had to define a new constructor, i.e., `myclass(const myclassRef<T>& r)`. And of course change the parameters for the two operators.

Changes are mark in code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct myclass;

template <class T>
struct myclassRef
{
    T* i;

    myclassRef(myclass<T>* A)
    {
        i = &A->i;
    }

    T& get()
    {
        return *i;
    }

    T get() const // Added as part of the answer
    {
        return *i;
    }

    friend class myclass<T>; // Added as part of the answer
};

template <class T>
struct myclass
{
    T i;

    myclass() = default;
    myclass(const myclass&) = default;
    myclass(T _i) : i(_i) {}
    myclass(const myclassRef<T>& r) : i(*r.i) {} // Added as part of the answer

    myclassRef<T> ref()
    {
        return myclassRef<T>(this);
    }

    T& get()
    {
        return i;
    }

    T get() const
    {
        return i;
    }
};

template <template <class> class Mlhs, template <class> class Mrhs, class T>  // Added as part of the answer
Mlhs<T>& operator+=(Mlhs<T>& lhs, const Mrhs<T>& rhs)
{
    lhs.get() += rhs.get();
    return lhs;
}

template <template <class> class Mlhs, template <class> class Mrhs, class T>  // Added as part of the answer
myclass<T> operator+(const Mlhs<T>& lhs, const Mrhs<T>& rhs)
{
    myclass<T> res(lhs);
    res += rhs;
    return res;
}

int main() {
    myclass<int> A(5);
    myclass<int> B(2);

    auto C = A + B;

    std::cout << C.i << std::endl;

    auto D = C.ref();

    A = D + B;

    std::cout << A.i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use inner classes. Instead, you should build two *global* operators, which exist outside both classes like this:

```
T operator+(const myclassRef<int>&, const myclass<int>&)
```

and the overload

```
T operator+(const myclass<int>&, const myclassRef<int>&)
```

Where `T` is the return type that you decide upon. If either of these functions require private data within the classes, then make the functions a `friend` of your two classes by putting these declarations in the class declarations:

```
friend T operator+(const myclassRef<int>&, const myclass<int>&);
friend T operator+(const myclass<int>&, const myclassRef<int>&);
```

Moving on, you might want to make these functions templates on the type of `myclassRef`, although only more modern compilers support making template functions friends.

Comment: I guess there is no way around doing this. But with several functions taking a mix of both types as parameters it kinda becomes a mess.

Comment: But at least it's a "contained mess" if you know what I mean.